# Send data from 1 activity to other activity via intent in android.. i want send SongName to next activity

Tags: android

```
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Player.class);   
String SongName = SpinSongSelector.getSelectedItem().toString ();   
startActivity (in);
```

i wan to send SongName to next Activity

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your first activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Player.class);
String SongName = SpinSongSelector.getSelectedItem().toString ();
intent.putExtra("message", SongName);
startActivity(intent);
```

and then in second activity get your string like below

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String message = bundle.getString("message");
```

then set this string to text-view (This is not necessary but just for your reference, if you want to check whether you got correct string or not)

```
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_resource_textview);    
txtView.setText(message);
```

Comment: Can you accept the answer by clicking right below my answer, Since you are new to SO, check this, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

use this line before startActivty :

```
intent.putExtra("SongName",SongName);
```

then retrieve it from the target activty.

Answer (score 0):

just use

first activity to send :

```
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Player.class);   
String SongName = SpinSongSelector.getSelectedItem().toString ();   
in.putExtra("data",SongName);
startActivity (in);
```

to receive in another activity:

```
String Sname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("data");
```

to see the details of intents refer here : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html